What is the best lighting & shadow setup for mininal draw calls and triangles?
I have been testing out various lighting and shadow settings in Unity since during play mode the stats are showing a much higher set pass call and triangle count to what I know my model has. I have since learnt that due to the way Unity renders, some objects (eg. point lights) increase draw calls, while some settings(eg. casting shadows, receiving shadows) increase triangle count.
I am looking for a lighting setup that will minimise draw calls and triangle counts. I am thinking of using only 1 directional light, and some kind of blob shadow/fake projected shadow for the characters, and perhaps bake shadows for all the static objects? I will have a basic day/night cycle but I think if I bake the shadows at a certain angle so they're not too big and obvious the fact that they don't move shouldn't matter so much. Or maybe I should do a blob shadow for everything?
If I could please get some more insight into what lighting/shadow settigs minimise draw calls and tri counts that would be appreciated.

How about using the "No shadow" option ? That would be best for mobile phones.

Yes turning off Unity's shadows completely could be a start, but what alternative to Unity's shadows would I use instead that's better performant?

The minimal triangle/call count is to just render nothing. Obviously that's not what you want. So really what you need is "minimal triangles/calls to achieve this visual target". If you add an example image of the kind of look you want, we can better recommend efficient techniques to achieve it. Different types of scenes can sometimes offer different optimization opportunities.

I am not looking for a specific look other than as mentioned using one directional light and having shadows appear in some form for all objects. At the expense of answering my own question, I included a few examples of what I already know (point lights, casting/receiving shadows), I am looking for what other options I need to consider, such as baked shadows, projectors, ambient occlusion etc and which combination of these is most optimised. Does that help?
